# Is Microsoft trying to brush the Diagnostics Tracking Service under the rug?

Tags: user-tracking, spyware, microsoft

I was working my way through disabling all of the spyware Microsoft has put into Windows 7 when I came across this Google result:

[image]

> "Sep 11, 2015 - Describes an update that **enables the Diagnostics
>   Tracking Service** in Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 7
>   SP1, and Windows ..."

The description of that result clearly states that the **KB3022345** Windows update **enables the Diagnostics Tracking Service** yet if you click the actual link or even the cached version of the link, that information is nowhere to be found. In fact there is no mention of the **Diagnostics Tracking Service** anywhere on that page.

Furthermore, searching for **"Diagnostics Tracking Service"** on Google yields no in depth explanation from any official Microsoft page as to what this service is used for. The only information I was able to gather about this service is that which is provided in services.msc:

> "The Diagnostics Tracking Service enables data collection about
>   functional issues in Windows components."

I'm not sure if this is a glitch on Google's end or if Microsoft is deliberately trying to throw users off from knowing about the **Diagnostics Tracking Service**. What worries me is if this is in fact the work of Microsoft, why are they going to such lengths to hide the information? I mean it's just sending out crash reports and hardware info right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96713/how-does-windows-10-allow-microsoft-to-spy-on-you/96902#96902 I know this is Windows 7 specific but addresses the same concerns?

Comment: Windows update is a double-edged sword.