# Microsoft is spying me. What can I do?

Tags: windows, privacy, windows-10, microsoft

I was getting into my Windows 10 configuration and I saw a lot of options which are sending data to Microsoft. Telemetries, tracking, statistics... even sharing Windows updates on my PC to other users!

I guess legally there is nothing to do - the EULA covers them for "all damage done" to the users... I was investigating this and I have three questions:

- Is "Windows update sharing" like p2p old style sharing? If yes, what about my bandwidth? Does Microsoft care about it in some way?
- Are there any good guides about how to restrict all the Windows 10 options to stop sending sensitive data to Microsoft to do it manually setting every option without using a software for blocking?
- Is legal on my side to restrict sending this data even after accepting the EULA? I mean by using software like [Blackbird](http://www.getblackbird.net/).

Comment: Windows settings are more of a SuperUser-type question. Legal questions are off-topic here.

Comment: These answers cover most of your question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96713/how-does-windows-10-allow-microsoft-to-spy-on-you?rq=1

Comment: https://www.privacytools.io/#win10. You can only do so much, though. I suggest you use another OS.

Comment: this isn't information security related but this is very very easy to find on Google. http://arstechnica.co.uk/information-technology/2015/08/windows-10-doesnt-offer-much-privacy-by-default-heres-how-to-fix-it/ and http://www.howtogeek.com/224981/how-to-stop-windows-10-from-uploading-updates-to-other-pcs-over-the-internet/  No comment on the legal question.

Comment: "Microsoft is spying me" - they really aren't. They are collecting telemetry to try and make your experiences with their hardware and software better so that they can sell more hardware and software! Unlike Google and Facebook, for example, who both have vested interests in you because their main revenue is advertising, Microsoft don't have that issue. Yes it seems rather intrusive but the data they collect is rapidly aggregated and not intentionally tied to personal data as advertising data is.

Comment: Considering Linux?

Comment: Of course I am a Linux user too. But sometimes and for some specific purposes I use Windows 10.